# Classnotfoundexception causes SimpleMessagelistenerContainer stop

Tags: spring-amqp

I found when listener throw a classnotfoundexception, the simplemessagelistenercontainer will stop and not work for sequence message.

I have set defaultrejectqueue false, should I also catch all exception and rethrow a amqprejectrequeueexception?

> 2015-11-17 14:15:59.808 ERROR 27121 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer thread error, thread abort. java.lang.NullPointerException: null         at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434) ~[na:1.7.0_45]         at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353) ~[na:1.7.0_45]         at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341) ~[na:1.7.0_45]         at com.ibm.cds.common.util.Settings.loadSettingResource(Settings.java:73) ~[cds_common-1.0.0.jar!/:61]         at com.ibm.cds.common.util.Settings.init(Settings.java:61) ~[cds_common-1.0.0.jar!/:61]         at com.ibm.cds.common.util.Settings.(Settings.java:40) ~[cds_common-1.0.0.jar!/:61]         ... 22 common frames omitted Wrapped by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null         at com.ibm.cds.common.util.TemplateUtils.(TemplateUtils.java:57) ~[cds_common-1.0.0.jar!/:61]         at com.ibm.cds.oss.response.ResizeServer.sendMail(ResizeServer.java:377) ~[cds_backend_service-1.0.0.jar!/:61]         at com.ibm.cds.oss.response.ResizeServer.endProcess(ResizeServer.java:330) ~[cds_backend_service-1.0.0.jar!/:61]         at com.ibm.cds.oss.response.AbsResponse.excute(AbsResponse.java:88) ~[cds_backend_service-1.0.0.jar!/:61]         at com.ibm.pmc.bss.message.services.OperationResponseService.handleOssResultResponse(OperationResponseService.java:79) ~[pmc-bss-messaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]         at com.ibm.pmc.bss.message.services.OperationResponseService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$30aa261b.invoke() ~[spring-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]         at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]         at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:649) ~[spring-aop-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]         at com.ibm.pmc.bss.message.services.OperationResponseService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a3025491.handleOssResultResponse() ~[spring-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]         at com.ibm.pmc.bss.message.components.Consumer.receive(Consumer.java:24) ~[pmc-bss-messaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]         at com.ibm.pmc.bss.message.DynamicMessageListenerContainerRegistry$2.onMessage(DynamicMessageListenerContainerRegistry.java:218) ~[pmc-bss-messaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT] at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:800) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]         at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:691) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]         at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]         at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:183) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]         at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1345) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]         at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:661) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]         at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1096) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]         at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1080) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]         at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$800(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]         at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1190) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45] 2015-11-17 14:15:59.812 ERROR 27121 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Stopping container from aborted consumer 2015-11-17 14:15:59.817  INFO 27121 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Waiting for workers to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean; if there's a class not found during initialization then, of course, the container won't start.

If the listener throws a `ClassNotFoundException` during normal message processing then the message will be rejected (and either requeued or not depending on configuration); but the container won't stop.

You need to explain exactly what you mean, including a stack trace (edit the question - don't try to put a stack trace in a comment).

**EDIT**

There is not a class not found exception there, just a null pointer exception:

> 2015-11-17 14:15:59.808 ERROR 27121 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer thread error, thread abort. java.lang.NullPointerException: null at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434) ~[na:1.7.0_45] at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353) ~[na:1.7.0_45] at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341) ~[na:1.7.0_45] at com.ibm.cds.common.util.Settings.loadSettingResource(Settings.java:73) ~[cds_common-1.0.0.jar!/:61] at com.ibm.cds.common.util.Settings.init(Settings.java:61) ~

which is a fatal error

> 14:15:59.812 ERROR 27121 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Stopping container from aborted consumer

You need to fix your code so the container can start.

Comment: sorry,i paste the complete log.

Comment: the container stopped

Comment: yes,i understand.but the class throw exception comes from external,it is not under my control. Is a good strategy that i catch this exception and log it?

Comment: Yes; you will have to catch it, but it's not clear that your application will work properly - you will have to check with your software vendor and/or otherwise figure out how to configure it properly so it doesn't throw an NPE. It looks like it's trying to find some properties file but has poor diagnostics.